# store multiple random numbers in an array : PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am generating 10 random numbers at the same time using for loop.

But I want is that I want to store that no's as ann array Values.

right now I am getting the data as following:

```
92278106394
```

Here is the simple `php` code that I have created.

```
for($i=0; $i<10 ; $i++)
 {
   $random= []; 
   $random = rand(1,10) ;

   echo json_encode($random);
 }
```

**Expectation:**

What I really want is the data in an array as shown in the following :

```
[9,2,2,7,8,10,6,3,9,4]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code creates a variable `$random` in the loop which is an empty array, then sets the variable to an int which is returned by [rand](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php).

Then you pass that int to json_encode which will return a string.

So you get that result because for every iteration you echo the int returned from rand as a string.

You could put the array outside of the loop and add the random to it for each iteration

```
$random= [];
for($i=0; $i<10 ; $i++)
{
    $random[] = rand(1,10) ;
}

print_r($random);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$array= [];
for($i=0; $i<10 ; $i++)
 {
   $random = rand(1,10) ;

   array_push($array, $random);

 }  
   var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create unique number with array ,unmatched all value ...

```
$unique=[];

while(count($unique)<10)
{
    $rand=rand(1,100);

    if(!in_array($rand,$unique))
    {
          $unique[]=$rand;

     }



}

print_r($unique);
```

If want to no unique

```
 $array=[];

 foreach (range(1,10) as $a)
   {
         $array[]=rand(1,100);

    }

print_r($array);
```